# Cannot execute just compiled binary file

Tags: command-line, executable, fortran

And once again, typical question: "cannot run executable file".

I Installed Virtual Box ver: 4.2.16
and on that Ubuntu.

I compiled several fotran codes with command (maybe it should be noted that I was at that moment ask to install gfortran, so I did.):

```
gfortran -o iri iritest.for irisub.for irifun.for iritec.for iridreg.for igrf.for cira.for iriflip.for
```

I got some warnings but no error. Then I wrote `. iri` and got:

```
 bash: . : iri: cannot execute binary file
```

As I read many A/Q about it on this page: here are the helpful information:

```
uname -a

Linux pavel-VirtualBox 3.5.0-43-genereic #66~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 24 14:55:08 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i 386 GNU/Linux
```

file iri

```
iri: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (used shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=0xac4e2cda297fb7fc0dbea9bff7c88dfdb417c297, not stripped
```

file /bin/bash

```
/bin/bash: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (used shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=0x64552078250a29637d1678751065aa4b5ee35222, not stripped
```

I also tried `chmod +x iri` and got the same result. However I think that is was unnecessary as the output of ls -l before was:

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 pavel pavel 1170853 Nov 10 13:30 iri
```

I also sent the file to windows and of course, it has no idea what to do with it. As the file and OS specifications are the same, I have no idea why the Ubuntu refuses to execute the file. Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To execute a binary file that is in the current directory (but not on your executable path) the correct syntax is

```
./iri
```

(note the `/`). The command you gave (with a space between the `.` and the filename) attempts to *source* the file as a script in the current shell - see `help source`

```
$ . hello
bash: .: hello: cannot execute binary file
$ 
$ ./hello
Hello world!
$
```

Comment: _facepalm_ Sure, that was the point, I lost about 3 hours on that. Thank you.